# Spring Security and H2: How to hash passwords

Tags: hash, spring-security, h2

I'm inserting users into a H2 database as follows:

```
insert into users (id,username,password) VALUES(1,'user','password');
```

I'm also using spring security. Usually to hash passwords I'd configure Spring like this:

```
<bean id = "encoder" class = "org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder"/>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <security:password-encoder ref="encoder" />-->
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-man
```

and put a hash function into the insert statement. The H2 documentation suggests I need to do this:

```
insert into users (id,username,password) VALUES(1 vg,'user',HASH('SHA256', STRINGTOUTF8('Password'), 1000));
```

but when I do, the passwords don't seem to match. I expect I'm not configuring something properly, but google isn't helping me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you expect to match... You have two `insert` statements in your question. In the first you insert the password as plain text, in the other you insert the hash values. But you didn't show the code where you try to match the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the convesion in java, using spring

```
final StandardPasswordEncoder encoder = new StandardPasswordEncoder();
String hashedPassword = encoder.encode(aStringVarOfThePassword);
```